# How can I use an ACL in BIND to forward requests per zone selectively?

Tags: freebsd, dns, bind

I have some zones declared internally as forwards to another DNS, but there is a hefty amount of IP space we do not want to be forwarded in this manner for these zones. These forwards are for very specific zone declarations and I'm not certain if there even is a way to use an ACL for this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit, here's an example using example.com:

acl "forwardees" {
  10.0.0.0/8;
};

zone "example.com" in {
    type forward;
    forwarders { 1.2.3.4; };
};

---

When doing a lookup of example.com, I would want only members of forwardees to get forwarded to 1.2.3.4. If you are not a member of forwardees, I would want it to be as if that zone entry doesn't exist and a recursive should be done.

Hopefully that spells it out better than I could word it myself.

Comment: Does this cover your question?  http://serverfault.com/questions/99101/conditional-dns-forwarding-with-named-on-linux  If not can you be more specific?

Comment: @Zoredache Not really, but I did give an example which hopefully meets the more specificity request.

Comment: Perhaps a typical split horizon setup?  http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-bind9-named-configure-views/